# flask service not working inside docker container

Tags: python, docker

I had the Dockerfile here for which i am able to build the image. The problem is that the program execution is unable to read a file in a subdirectory path even though the file is there.

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
MAINTAINER Vivek Kaul "vkaul11@gmail.com"
#Install Ubuntu pkgs
COPY apt.conf /etc/apt/apt.conf
COPY . /product_info
WORKDIR /product_info
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        ca-certificates \
        vim \
        git \
        python \
        python-pip \
        curl \
        wget \
        lsof \
        libmysqlclient-dev \
        python-dev \
        python-mysqldb \
        build-essential \
        && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

#PYTHON requirements

ENV HTTPS_PROXY "https://gec-proxy-svr.homeoffice.wal-mart.com:8080/"

RUN python --version
RUN pip install pip --upgrade
RUN pip install --upgrade setuptools
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt


EXPOSE 9000


RUN ls -la /product_info/key_matching/data

ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c", "python key_matching/key_matching_endpoint.py"]
```

and when I run `docker run -p 9000:9000 product_info` I get error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "key_matching/key_matching_endpoint.py", line 5, in <module>
    from key_matching import find_keys
  File "/product_info/key_matching/key_matching.py", line 11, in <module>
    from label_keys import key_to_label
  File "/product_info/key_matching/label_keys.py", line 67, in <module>
    with open('data/all_keys_sorted.txt', 'r') as f:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data/all_keys_sorted.txt'
```

I am able to run everything outside of docker and also the output of

```
RUN ls -la /product_info/key_matching/data
```

shows that the file data/all_keys_sorted.txt is there in the working directory.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 45713 Sep  5 12:32 all_keys_sorted.txt
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Sep  5 12:36 thresholds
```

I am unable to understand the reason for this as it works when I run everything outside docker

Comment: Try `docker exec -it your_container bash` to enter your container and have a check about that file.

Comment: Your `WORKDIR` is `/product_info` therefore the code is looking for `data/all_keys_sorted.txt` in `/product_info/data/all_keys_sorted.txt` but it's really in `/product_info/key_matching/data/all_keys_sorted.txt`.

Comment: Why is that the data/all_keys_sorted.txt is relative path from my python file location not from work directory

Comment: The container is not made from the image  because of this error

Comment: You have to remember that all processes, sans changing directory within code, will attempt to open relative paths from current directory. In docker container, WORKDIR is your current working directory when the executable starts.

Comment: You are right actually thanks!